# TS React: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript

I am using asp.net core and react.js for an application and everything is happening in visual studio. I get an error when I use

```
ajax.onSuccess = function (value: any) {
        dataManager = value;
    };
```

ERROR:Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'ajax' must be if type 'Ajax', but here has type 'any'.

I tried to declare the ajax variable with 'LET'

```
let ajax = new Ajax('Home/GetData', 'GET', false);
```

but i can't use 'let' inside a class.

Scheduler.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScheduleComponent, Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda, Inject } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Ajax } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { DataManager, ODataV4Adaptor, Query } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';

export default class Scheduler extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>  {

    private dataManager: object = [];
    ajax = new Ajax('Home/GetData', 'GET', false);
    ajax.onSuccess = function (value: any) {         HERE
        dataManager = value;
    };
    render() { 
        return <ScheduleComponent height='550px' selectedDate={new Date(2018, 1, 15)} eventSettings={{ dataSource: dataManager }}>
            <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month]} />

        </ScheduleComponent>;
    }
}
```

How can I fix the problem so that I can use ajax varible?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you should use the `constructor` function

```
export default class Scheduler extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>  {

    private dataManager: object = [];
    ajax: someType; // Define the type here for ajax if you want to
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        let ajax = new Ajax('Home/GetData', 'GET', false);
        ajax.onSuccess = function (value: any) {
            // Callback func body
        };
        this.ajax = ajax
    }
    render() { 
        return <ScheduleComponent/>;
    }
}
```